# Difference between bo-html and bo-text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, bindonce

While reading the documentation of the [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) directive, I wonder what is the difference between `bo-html`and `bo-text`.

- `bo-html`:

> evaluates "markup" and render it as html inside the element

- `bo-text`:

> evaluates "text" and print it as text inside the element

So, I expected this code to work:

```
<span bo-html="<strong>SomeText</strong>"></span>
```

But I got this:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression
```

`<strong>` being a basic **markup**, isn't it?

If this can't work (maybe a syntax issue..), what is the real difference between `bo-text` and `bo-html`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to throw a string into bo-html, you need to declare it as a string because it's looking for a variable.

```
<span bo-html="'<strong>SomeText</strong>'"></span>
```

another way:

```
$scope.myVariable = '<strong>SomeText</strong>';
<span bo-html="myVariable"></span>
```

The difference is just as you copied above. You can see the difference by example:

```
$scope.myVariable = '<strong>SomeText</strong>';
<span bo-html="myVariable"></span> //<strong>SomeText</strong> as HTML
<span bo-text="myVariable"></span> //<strong>SomeText</strong> as text
```